# How to delete all markdown cells in jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I want to delete all markdown cells from a jupyter notebook. The only possible way to do this, as I see, to download it as .py file, then copy and paste in a new jupyter notebook. Is there a way to do this without breaking cell structure?

Comment: .ipynb is essentially a json, you can try opening it as such, cleaning and saving in a script.

Answer (score 1):

[nbformat](https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) can be used to do that:

```py
import nbformat as nbf
ntbk = nbf.read("old_notebook.ipynb", nbf.NO_CONVERT)
new_ntbk = ntbk
new_ntbk.cells = [cell for cell in ntbk.cells if cell.cell_type != "markdown"]
nbf.write(new_ntbk, "no_markdown_notebook.ipynb", version=nbf.NO_CONVERT)
```

For less 'broad-strokes' notebook cleaning, Chris Holdgraf's [nbclean](https://github.com/choldgraf/nbclean) is my go-to tool for this type of thing.

(This answer was adapted from code to do the opposite process: [Delete all code cells except markdown text](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/delete-all-code-cells-except-markdown-text/3072?u=fomightez)).