# What is the best python data structure for the contents of jupyter notebook files?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to convert jupyter notebooks to python files, but before doing so, I want to filter their contents, e.g. remove all markdown cells; therefore the gui export functionality or calling nbconvert from the command line doesn't exactly satisfy my needs.

What I want to do therefore is to first load the contents of the notebook into a python container, e.g. a list of dictionaries, and then do the filtering on the container, save the remaining contents as a jupyter notebook that is then exported to a python file.

**Question:**

- what data structure is most appropriate for holding the contents of a jupyter notebook?
- Are there any libraries that already enable the manipulation of jupyter notebooks with python?

Comment: Notebooks are dictionaries stored in JSON, so I think you should just be able to load the notebook into a Python object using `json.load()`

Comment: You may be able to adapt the code for Jupytext to do what you want. [Jupytext](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html) converts Jupyter `.ipynb` files to a number of text forms. One of them is `.py` scripts. Usually they need further work if the source already wasn't pure Python.  .... You'll want to look into the Python module nbformat for removing markdown cells, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71244733/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59776611/8508004) for more about nbformat and examples. nbformat already has the concepts of types of cells baked in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An IPython notebook is just JSON. You can just parse the JSON.

The description of the format is [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/notebook/nbformat.html).

Briefly:

> At the highest level, a Jupyter notebook is a dictionary with a few
> keys:
>
> - metadata (dict)
> - nbformat (int)
> - nbformat_minor (int)
> - cells (list)

There are markdown cells:

```json
{
  "cell_type" : "markdown",
  "metadata" : {},
  "source" : ["some *markdown*"],
}
```

And code cells:

```
{
  "cell_type" : "code",
  "execution_count": 1, # integer or null
  "metadata" : {
      "collapsed" : True, # whether the output of the cell is collapsed
      "autoscroll": False, # any of true, false or "auto"
  },
  "source" : ["some code"],
  "outputs": [{
      # list of output dicts (described below)
      "output_type": "stream",
      ...
  }],
}
```

But I'm not sure why:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to script mynotebook.ipynb
```

Doesn't work for you.

Comment: nbconvert is fine for converting notebooks to python files, but not for filtering the notebook's contents before the conversion.